# How to print the longest word in a file by using combination of grep and wc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

iam trining to find the longest word in a text file.
i tried it and find out the no of characters in the longest word in a file 
by using the command

```
wc -L
```

i need to print the longest word By using this number and grep command .

Comment: How many words per line do you have? With awk it might be easier

Comment: have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962466/finding-the-longest-word-in-a-text-file

Comment: 1 word per line. Iam using a standard file /usr/share/dict/words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *must* use the two commands give, I'd suggest:

```
grep -E ".{$(wc -L < test.txt)}" test.txt
```

The command substitution is used to build the correct brace expression to match the line(s) with exactly the given number of characters. `-E` is needed to enable extended regular expression support; otherwise, the braces need to be escaped: `grep ".\{...\}" test.txt`.

Using an `awk` command that makes a single pass through the file may be faster.

Comment: Thanks; I verified that you needed either `-E` or escaped braces, but forgot to update the answer after the test.